# Azure automation can not start vm because credential have changed?

Tags: azure, automation, azure-automation

I have an automation account in azure that starts and stops some VMs. I have no issue stopping the VMs, but It can not start them. I assume that this is  related to recent password change that we did. I know that we need to change something in Azure PowerShell, but I don't know what to change and how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

In what way you start and stop VMs through Azure Automation account? Is it using Start Stop VM solution or using a custom runbook with [Start-AzVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/start-azvm?view=azps-4.7.0) and [Stop-AzVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/stop-azvm?view=azps-4.7.0) cmdlets.

If its using Start Stop VM Solution then see if [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/start-stop-vm) troubleshooting guide helps to resolve your issue.

If its using custom runbook then it would be easy to diagnose the issue if you can provide your runbook.